# Excluding certain attributes from being labeled in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, labeling, layers

I am using ArcMap 10.1, and i am labeling a roadway system but would like to exclude certain road labels from being displayed.

Comment: Are these dynamic labels or part of an annotation feature class?

Comment: Perhaps this guide might help: [Using label classes to label features from the same layer differently](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_label_classes_to_label_features_from_the_same_layer_differently/00s80000000v000000/)

Comment: Im not sure I know the difference.  They are labeling based upon a certain attribute field.

Answer (score 5):

Right click add the labeling toolset
[image]

Click on 'label manager' the icon next to the Labeling drop down menu...
[image]

When the label manager appears choose the layer you want to work on on the left panel, then the label field from the drop down menu on the right. Then at the bottom use the 'SQL Query' option to query the records you want to label.

Comment: How would i query every road expect one?

Comment: for example if the road id of the one you d not want to label is 5. Then you can use [roadId] <> 5. will label every road except those that have id # 5. For string you can use not([roadname] = 'Main') for example.